# rpcbind/nfs fails, failed to create RPC listeners, exiting

Tags: centos, nfs, pxe

My system crashed while a script was running that deploys a pxe boot system (software is called DRBL).  Now I can't get rpcbind, nfs, or ypbind to start properly.  I'm chasing a series of errors which I'll recount here.  I think the problem all surrounds rpcbind but I don't know for sure.  I'm thinking some part of the files system must have been corrupted in the crash but I haven't found out the problem.  This is for Centos 6, 2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64.

/var/log/messages error on boot:

```
May 25 09:01:48 tebow rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with     "rpcbind -w"
May 25 09:07:23 tebow rpc.statd[4122]: Version 1.2.3 starting
May 25 09:07:23 tebow rpc.statd[4122]: Initializing NSM state
May 25 09:07:23 tebow rpc.statd[4122]: failed to create RPC listeners,     exiting
May 25 09:08:09 tebow ypbind: NIS service failed to register to rpcbind.
May 25 09:08:10 tebow rpc.ypxfrd[4469]: unable to register     (YPXFRD_FREEBSD_PROG, YPXFRD_FREEBSD_VERS, udp).
May 25 09:08:12 tebow rpc.yppasswdd[4743]: unable to register yppaswdd udp     service.
May 25 09:39:12 tebow ypbind: NIS service failed to register to rpcbind.
May 25 09:39:13 tebow rpc.yppasswdd[15363]: unable to register yppaswdd udp     service.
May 25 09:39:14 tebow rpc.ypxfrd[15408]: unable to register     (YPXFRD_FREEBSD_PROG, YPXFRD_FREEBSD_VERS, udp).
```

RPC issues:

```
[root@tebow drbl]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind is stopped
[root@tebow drbl]# service rpcbind start
[root@tebow drbl]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind is stopped
[root@tebow drbl]# service rpcbind restart
Stopping rpcbind:                                          [FAILED]

[root@tebow drbl]# rpcinfo -p localhost
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused

[root@tebow drbl]# rpcinfo -u tebow nfs 2
rpcinfo: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
program 100003 version 2 is not available

[root@tebow drbl]# service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd is stopped
nfsd is stopped
rpc.rquotad is stopped
```

If there is a way to simply reset rpcbind/nfs all to initial installation values I'd be happy too, but doing yum reinstalls, or yum remove/yum install of rpcbind and nfs has not alleviated the problem.

**Update 1**:
I updated to the latest kernel "2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64" and updated to the latest rpcbind and nfs, but the same error occurs.  On a fresh bootup, the errors in /var/log/messages are:

```
May 25 11:30:11 tebow yum[7059]: Updated: rpcbind-0.2.0-12.el6.x86_64
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Version 1.2.3 starting
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Initializing NSM state
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Failed to register (statd, 1, udp): svc_reg() err: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Failed to register (statd, 1, tcp): svc_reg() err: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Failed to register (statd, 1, udp6): svc_reg() err: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: Failed to register (statd, 1, tcp6): svc_reg() err: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
May 25 11:39:46 tebow rpc.statd[4297]: failed to create RPC listeners, exiting
May 25 11:40:33 tebow ypbind: NIS service failed to register to rpcbind.
May 25 11:40:34 tebow rpc.ypxfrd[4645]: unable to register (YPXFRD_FREEBSD_PROG, YPXFRD_FREEBSD_VERS, udp).
May 25 11:41:13 tebow rpc.yppasswdd[14594]: unable to register yppaswdd udp service.
```

Also, when checking nfslock I get this interesting error about rpc.statd:

```
[root@tebow ~]# /etc/init.d/nfslock status
rpc.statd dead but pid file exists
```

Comment: Generic post-crash advice: run `rpm -V -a` to check whether any executables have been damaged.